# Solutions to systems of linear inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I want to obtain canonical representations of solutions to sets of linear inequalities.

For example,
$x \ge y \ge z \ge 0, x - y - z < -1$ and at least one of $z > 0$, $-1 \ge x - y$ and $x - y \ge 1$.

I have tried to encode this in two ways:

```
CylindricalDecomposition[x ≥ y && y ≥ z && z ≥ 0 && x - y - z < -1 && (z > 0 || -1 ≥ x - y || x - y ≥ 1) , {x, y, z}]
```

and

```
CylindricalDecomposition[{x ≥ y, y ≥ z, z ≥ 0, x - y - z < -1, (z > 0 || -1 ≥ x - y || x - y ≥ 1)} , {x, y, z}]
```

both of which evaluate, in WolframAlpha, to `False`.

There are values of $\left( x, y, z \right)$ that satisfy these inequalities, e.g. $\left( \frac{8}{4}, \frac{7}{4}, \frac{6}{4} \right)$.  Thus, I believe that I am encoding the problem incorrectly.

1. can I improve my syntax in the `CylindricalDecomposition` call?
2. should I be using a different command in the first place (or even different software)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Mathematica version 13.0: The first example evaluates to: `x > 1 && (1 + x)/2 < y <= x && 1 + x - y < z <= y`

Comment: @DanielHuber that may solve it for me - I was using WolframAlpha, which may be understrength.

Comment: yes, working well in Mathematica v13 now

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = x >= y && y >= z && z >= 0 && 
   x - y - z < -1 && (z > 0 || -1 >= x - y || x - y >= 1);

expr2 = expr // FullSimplify

(* x >= y && 1 + x < y + z && y >= z *)

expr3 = expr // Reduce

(* y > 1 && y <= x < -1 + 2 y && 1 + x - y < z <= y *)

rgns = ImplicitRegion[#, {x, y, z}] & /@ {expr, expr2, expr3};
```

The regions are equal

```
RegionEqual @@ rgns

(* True *)
```

Graphically,

```
RegionPlot3D[#, {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, {z, 0, 50},
   PlotPoints -> 150, MaxRecursion -> 2,
   PlotLabel -> #, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@
 {expr, expr2, expr3}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @bob-hanlon: given multiple results of CylindricalDecomposition (e.g. expr_1 ... expr_n), do you know the best way to (i) present their union (in cylindrical notation), and (ii) show that the intersection of any distinct expr_i and expr_j is empty?

Comment: No, I don't. You should probably ask a mathematician.